# Vuetify dynamic height for v-img

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a container that is not 100% height of the page, it is 80% plus 60px on top and on bottom.
So the image inside should inherit the height of the container.

Using the `<img />` and a little of CSS it is easy to achieve but I wish to add a template with loading spinner and so I started using the `<v-img>` for it.

I can see I can set the `height` or the `max-height` and so I did a method to calculate the parent height minus the 120px to get the exact image height, and it is working as expected.

The issue is when the user resize the window, I can see the method to be called and updating the value but the vuetify element is not responsive to the new values and so the image is bigger or smaller than container:

```
<div id="photoWrapper" class="photo-wrapper">
  <v-img
    :src="photo.url"
    :contain="true"
    :max-height="wrapperHeight()"
  >
    <template v-slot:placeholder>
      <v-layout fill-height align-center justify-center ma-0>
        <v-progress-circular
          indeterminate
          color="tertiary"
        ></v-progress-circular>
      </v-layout>
    </template>
  </v-img>
</div>
```

Code:

```
data() {
  return {
    mounted: false
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.mounted = true
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.wrapperHeight)
  this.wrapperHeight()
},
methods: {
  wrapperHeight() {
    if (!this.mounted) return
    console.log(document.getElementById('photoWrapper').offsetHeight - 120)
    const height = document.getElementById('photoWrapper').offsetHeight - 120
    return height
  }
}
```

The method is always called on screen resize, but the image is not responsive.
How can I do it? I also tried to move the `wrapperHeight` to be a computed property.

Comment: You are calling wrapperHeight in mounted (return value unused), and also trying to bind to a property. You should be using computed property if you want to bind. That wont work here, because vue wont know when to trigger it since document.** functions are not reactive. you could assign the result of wrapper height to a data member and use that instead.

Comment: please enrich this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/dyozOzO?editors=1010) with more details and let's debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do a mix between computed and methods like so:

```
data() {
  return {
    mounted: false,
    containerHeight:
      document.getElementById('photoWrapper').offsetHeight - 120
  }
},
computed: {
  wrapperHeight() {
    if (!this.mounted) return
    const height = this.containerHeight
    return height
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.mounted = true
  window.addEventListener('resize', _.debounce(this.handleResize, 100))
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
},
methods: {
  handleResize() {
    this.containerHeight =
      document.getElementById('photoWrapper').offsetHeight - 120
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return the `${height}px` in the `wrapperHeight` method

Comment: Unfortunately no, vuetify accept `number | string`.

Comment: Hello Vlad, Please look into your answer formatting, your backticks were eaten up by the stackoverflow markdown engine.

Comment: Try making it a getter, not a method?

Comment: This is doing nothing because Vuetify accept 100 or "100px".

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your wrapperHeight is a computed property. That is correct and more performance than create it like method.

```
computed: {
      wrapperHeight() {
          if (!this.mounted) return
          console.log(document.getElementById('photoWrapper').offsetHeight - 120)
          const height = document.getElementById('photoWrapper').offsetHeight - 120
          return height
      }
  }
```

And 
    :max-height="wrapperHeight" not :max-height="wrapperHeight()"

Comment: It was my first attemp, I said it at the end of my question... It doesnt' work unfortunately. It get the first value at the beginning and then on resize it doesn't trigger the computed property anymore...